# Carrying disinfecting wipes in checked in luggage?

Tags: usa, air-travel, luggage, international-travel, covid-19

Is is allowed to carry disinfecting wipes (Clorox, Walmart brands) in checked-in luggage of international air travel originating from the US?

There is an article about sanitizers, but it doesn't mention disinfecting wipes: https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/more_info/?hazmat=26.  It looks like a container less than 500 ml is allowed, but again, it's sanitizer.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disinfecting wipes are fine in both check in and checked bags. https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/disinfecting-wipes

It's certainly somewhat illogical because you could get some liquids out of them but apparently not enough for the TSA to get worried. The same reasoning probably stands with the FAA too -- the amount of base you could possibly get out of a disinfecting wipe is so small and so diluted it can't damage the plane.

Of course, if you show up at the airport with a roller bag stuffed to the brim with handmade disinfecting wipes and someone notices, you will be asked a few rather pointed questions. After all as the source above notes:

> The final decision rests with the TSA officer on whether an item is allowed through the checkpoint.